# ASP.NET/XML: Convert XmlDataSource to HTML?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xmldatasource

How can I parse an remote xml file with XMLDataSource to HTML? Xpath?  Can someone show me a quick demo please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to just display your XML on a web page?  Here's a tutorial:

[Walkthrough: Creating a web page to display Display XML Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13ftcwy9%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: no, i want to take xml and convert to html.. like grab some variables from a xml feed and turn it into an anchor link surrounding an image tag